# Octobercms onSave update other model

Tags: model, relation, octobercms

I need to update the `status` field of the book in model relation when a loan is saved, but it is not working.

My code

```
class Lending extends Model
{

/**
 * @var string The database table used by the model.
 */
public $table = 'ribsousa_library_lendings';

/*
 * Relations
 */
public $belongsToMany = [
    'books' => [
        'Ribsousa\Library\Models\Book',
        'table' =>  'ribsousa_library_lendings_books',
        'order'      => 'title desc'
    ]
];

public function afterSave()
{

    $this->book->status = 1;
    $this->book->save();

}
}
```

The Error:

```
`"Indirect modification of overloaded property Ribsousa\Library\Models\Lending::$book has no effect" on line 95 of C:\wamp64\www\iepm.dev\plugins\ribsousa\library\models\Lending.php`
```

Comment: try `formAfterSave` https://octobercms.com/docs/api#formaftersave

Comment: updated my answer  please check it once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have try this `code` and `its working fine` can you try this one.

it's inside my `model which model I am saving` , so when `saving is done` I am `updating related demo model's` **status** field and seems `its working`.

```
public $belongsTo = [
    'demo' => 'HardikSatasiya\DemoTest\Models\Demo',
    'user' => 'RainLab\User\Models\User'
];

/**
 * @var string The database table used by the model.
 */
public $table = 'hardiksatasiya_demotest_relation';

public function afterSave() {
    $this->demo->status = 1;
    $this->demo->save();
}
```

### Update

It seems you have **updated answer** and It's Relation  **`is Many to Many`** so for now I have `no proper solution` for **updating multiple record at once**, **because** collection `update` method is not generating `proper query structure` so it throws error for `collection update`.

**But** I have other solution which `can fire multiple queries` but for now it `seems working solution for your issue`.

your Relation is `belongsToMany` sow we need different approch.

```
public function afterSave() {
    $this->books()->each(function($book) {
        $book->update(['status' => 1]);
        // if you get mass assign error -use this
        // $book->status = 1;
        // $book->save();

    });     
}
```

> Make sure your `Book` model don't have any `afterSave` logic and **if it has** then just make sure it **don't update your parent model** in your case `Lending`, as **it will call infinite loop**.

please try this and let us know.

Comment: Now I get the following error:

`Failed to mass assign status attribute of Model.`

Comment: I found the solution added in my model book:

`protected $fillable = ['status'];`

Comment: Thanks Hardik, for helping me!

Comment: cool glad it helped you , other wise you can also do `$book->status = 1; $book->save();` it will also work without mass assignment :)